# Using progress Dialog instead of progress bar in asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement this [**tutorial**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html), for handling Configuration changes while running background tasks. Everything works fine, and the app does not crash after a configuration change. In the tutorial, a progress bar is used to display progress. But in my own implementation i want to use a Progress Dialog.

I have used progress Dialog's lots of times, so calling it and getting to appear is not the problem. My problem is that unlike the progress Bar, the progress dialog gets dismissed on configuration change. Just like that.

Here is my code:

**My MainActivity:**

```
 private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;
 private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 private TextView mPercent;
 private Button mButton;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Log.i(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle)");
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 // Initialize views


 mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.task_button);
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if (mTaskFragment.isRunning()) {
  mTaskFragment.cancel();
 } else {
  mTaskFragment.start();
 }
 }
 });

 mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);



  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("task");

  // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
 // retained across a configuration change.
 if (mTaskFragment == null) {
 mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
 fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, "task").commit();  
 }

 if (mTaskFragment.isRunning()) {
 mButton.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
 } else {
 mButton.setText(getString(R.string.start));
 }
 }



 /****************************/
 /***** CALLBACK METHODS *****/
 /****************************/

 @Override
 public void onPreExecute() {
 Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute()");

 mProgressBar.setTitle("Wacky");
 mProgressBar.setMessage("wack");
 mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
 mProgressBar.show();
 mButton.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));

 mButton.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
 Toast.makeText(this, R.string.task_started_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onProgressUpdate(int percent) {
 //Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate(" + percent + "%)");

 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled() {
 Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled()");
 mButton.setText(getString(R.string.start));

 Toast.makeText(this, R.string.task_cancelled_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onPostExecute() {
 Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
 mButton.setText(getString(R.string.start));

 Toast.makeText(this, R.string.task_complete_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

**My headless Fragment that holds my asyncTask**

```
 /**
 *   This Fragment manages a single background task and retains itself across
 * configuration changes.
 */
 public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {
 public static final String TAG = TaskFragment.class.getSimpleName();

 /**
 * Callback interface through which the fragment can report the task's
 * progress and results back to the Activity.
 */

 public static interface TaskCallbacks {
    public void onPreExecute();
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percent);
    public void onCancelled();
    public void onPostExecute();
  }

 public TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
 public DummyTask mTask;
 public boolean mRunning;

 /**
 * Android passes us a reference to the newly created Activity by calling this
 * method after each configuration change.
 */
 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
 Log.i(TAG, "onAttach(Activity)");
 super.onAttach(activity);
 if (!(activity instanceof TaskCallbacks)) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement the TaskCallbacks interface.");
 }

 // Hold a reference to the parent Activity so we can report back the task's
 // current progress and results.
 mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
 }

 /**
 * This method is called only once when the Fragment is first created.
 */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Log.i(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle)");
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setRetainInstance(true);
 }

 /**
 * This method is <em>not</em> called when the Fragment is being retained
 * across Activity instances.
 */
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
 super.onDestroy();
 cancel();
 }

 /*****************************/
 /***** TASK FRAGMENT API *****/
 /*****************************/

 /**
 * Start the background task.
 */
 public void start() {
 if (!mRunning) {
  mTask = new DummyTask(this, mCallbacks);
  mTask.execute();
  mRunning = true;
 }
 }

 /**
 * Cancel the background task.
 */
 public void cancel() {
 if (mRunning) {
  mTask.cancel(false);
  mTask = null;
  mRunning = false;
 }
 }

 /**
 * Returns the current state of the background task.
 */
 public boolean isRunning() {
 return mRunning;
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Log.i(TAG, "onActivityCreated(Bundle)");
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 }
 }
```

**My Background Task** (in a seperate outer class)

```
 /**
 * A dummy task that performs some (dumb) background work and proxies progress
 * updates and results back to the Activity.
 */
 public class DummyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
private  TaskFragment fragment;
private TaskCallbacks callbacks;
private ProgressDialog mProgressBar;
MainActivity activity;

 public DummyTask(TaskFragment taskFragment, TaskCallbacks mCallbacks) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

  this.fragment = taskFragment;
  this.callbacks = mCallbacks;
}

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
 // Proxy the call to the Activity
 fragment.mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
 fragment.mRunning = true;
 }

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
 for (int i = 0; !isCancelled() && i < 100; i++) {

   //Log.i(TAG, "publishProgress(" + i + "%)");
   SystemClock.sleep(100);
   publishProgress(i);
 }
 return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
 // Proxy the call to the Activity
 fragment.mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate(percent[0]);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCancelled() {
 // Proxy the call to the Activity
 fragment.mCallbacks.onCancelled();
 fragment.mRunning = false;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
 // Proxy the call to the Activity
 fragment.mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
 fragment.mRunning = false;
 }
 }
```

I am thinking it is the context which i am passing the progress dialog in the onCreate method of my Main Activity.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, Activity is subclass of Context, you should know this already. Second, if Activity is destroyed, it is don't have a window anymore. Third, Dialog uses Context (read Activity) not because it wants so, but because it uses window associated with Activity to display itself.
It should be perfectly understandable, why after destroying activity during configuration change, Dialog no longer visible to you.

Method of preserving objects you using is good, but it can't preserve anything that would be destroyed during configuration change, such as any object that related to non-application Context, all this objects you need create manually every time Context changes.

You should use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` to store state of ProgressDialog (shown or not) and show it again in your `onCreate(Bunde)` using value stored in Bundle.

Just an example

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("SHOW_DIALOG", mProgressBar.isShowing());
}

//...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("SHOW_DIALOG") && mTaskFragment.isRunning()){
            mProgressBar.setTitle("Wacky");
            mProgressBar.setMessage("wack");
            mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressBar.show();
        }
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I tried it but the app crashes with a NullPointerException right at the point of reading  `savedInstanceState.getBoolean("SHOW_DIALOG") && mTaskFragment.isRunning()`. I've added the crash report to my question